# PHP/Symfony: Cannot trigger the event for FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony

I have a problem with subscribing events for FOSUserBundle (I am using [this](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html) tutorial).

Basically, I am trying to just redirect a user to specified route after login. I made a class, just like in the tutorial:

```
//src:src/AppBundle/EventsListener/LoginListener.php
```

```
namespace AppBundle\EventsListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class LoginListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN => 'onSecurityImplicitLogin',
        );
    }

    public function onSecurityImplicitLogin(FormEvent $event)
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('profile');
    }
}
```

And my services.yml looks like this:

```
services:
    login_listener:
            class: AppBundle\EventsListener\LoginListener
            arguments: ['@router']
            tags:
             - { name: 'kernel.event_subscriber' }
```

But it still redirects me to the "\" route. Can somebody help me find what's wrong? Besides, is this really the only way to define routes in this bundle?

And, by the way, are there any resources/manuals besides this one, "official docs"? I've found this manual very unclear and rough.

Thank you for concern!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that simple purpose you have just to add in `security.yml`:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        form_login:
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: profile
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Just one more thing - are login data stored in session/somewhere where I can retrieve it for my controller? Or maybe I should do it via Events?